# Correct ways to response a zip file to the request

Tags: php, curl, joomla3.0

There is a request for a zip file from a website to my site using curl/fopen. When request comes then a specific php method codes in my site gets all query string variable values in the requesting url, then makes various checks with those to verify the validity of the request(there are some kind of checks which i don't want to write for security reasons) then following code replies the zip file finally -

```
    header("Expires: 0");   
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="file name here"'); 
    header('Content-Length: '.filesize("/home/ttcc/content.zip"));
    header("Cache-Control: maxage=1");
    header("Pragma: public");
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
    ob_clean();
    flush();              
    if (!readfile("/home/ttcc/content.zip")) echo "some messages";
    exit();
```

that code works but is this the right way to response a zip file ? are there any faults or security leaks of it?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need any additional calculations before sending file as response, it is better to use **Web server** for this purpose. [Nginx](https://nginx.org/) will be a good choice to serve static files.

So request should not be passed to PHP, and processed by web server itself, like images and other static files.

If you need to check access rights or response with different files for the same request, you can use your code and make all calculations before it. Do it by means of PHP is pretty simple and convenient solution.

Comment: Actually don't feel secure to host files in another server other than mine coz it's a commercial file, dont know about ngix much.

Comment: File wil be hosted on your server. I suppose, you use `Apache`(httpd) and PHP to run your web service. So `Apache` **is** a Web server, like `Nginx`, it's just software you use to respond to HTTP requests